# PO-UI - Page Dynamic Table não está chamando url de metadata

Tags: angular, po-ui

*pergunta se refere a biblioteca PO-UI, mas não tenho direito de criar tag aqui no SO*
Tenho o seguinte componente:

```html
<po-page-dynamic-table
  p-service-api="http://localhost:5000/api/clientes">
</po-page-dynamic-table>
```

Na [documentação](https://po-ui.io/documentation/po-page-dynamic-table) diz que se usar via Rota e não definir metadado ele irá chamar o `serviceApi` com `/metadata` para pegar o metadado.

Quando uso componente direto ele não faz isso?

Tenho como definir a url do metadado de alguma forma? Ou quando usa o elemento dentro de um componente, ele não faz a busca sozinho?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você usa o componente direto você é responsável por atribuir as propriedades, ele só usa metadados quando você usa via rota.

```
// HTML
<po-page-dynamic-table
  [p-actions]="actions"
  [p-fields]="fields"
  p-service-api="http://localhost:5000/api/clientes">
</po-page-dynamic-table>

// TS
actions: PoPageDynamicTableAction = {
  new: this.onNew.bind(this),
  ...
};

fields: Array<PoPageDynamicTableFilters> = [
  { property: 'id', key: true },
  { property: 'name', filter: true },
  ...
];
```

Você pode fazer a requisição no ngOnInit da sua página e fazer a requisição também caso seja necessário ter o componente na sua aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

É feito a requisição para o metadados quando utiliza-se via rota, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]